# Xhr response return incomplete object

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, xmlhttprequest, find

I would do xhr request to an url then fetch all the images, add some attributes, push into the html page.
That's my simplified code:

```
function setStyle(image){
  var ratio = image.width/image.height;
  if(ratio>1){
    image.style.minHeight = '100%';
  }else{
    image.style.minWidth = '100%';
  }
  $('#gallery').innerHTML += image.parentNode.outerHTML;
}


function xhrRequest(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = this.response;
    if(data.indexOf('<img') !== -1){
      images = $(data).find('img');
      var len = images.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        setStyle(images[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "url");
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

I call xhrRequest() multiple times and the first time the images fetched with find() function works perfectly then the object become incomplete and the width and height properties are blank.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't get dimensions of an image until it has been loaded. Use load event. Also jQuery objects have no `innerHTML` property

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support but onload function should return the document completly loaded, am i wrong?

Comment: No...only the html response which is nothing more than a data string. The images won't load until that html is added to the dom or you create image elements from them. Don't confuse ajax load event with initial page load event

Comment: So if i want to get the size of an image before "inject" it in the dom, i have to create an image object?

Comment: Yes you would ....then use load event on that element object. You can iterate your current `images` object and add a load event to each one to get individual dimensions

Comment: I attatched eventListener on jquery object and seems work good.
I really appraciate your time, really really thanks.